# Изменить высоту карусели Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, карусель

Скажите пожалуйста, как изменить высоту карусели Bootstrap? Чтобы весь контент сохранялся, а в идеале и пропорции изображения.

Comment: Поясните, что значит "весь контент сохранялся"? Добавьте в вопрос свой код, чтобы стало понятнее, какого именно результата вы добиваетесь.

Comment: @Александр, если ответ помог Вам в решении задачи, пожалуйста, отметьте его галкой, расположенной слева, под стрелками голосования.

Answer (score 9):

### Растянуть изображения на всю ширину страницы

```
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/c69/f9c/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/650x250/9c6/cf9/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x200/69c/9cf/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### Задать карусели определённую высоту

Высота `.carousel-inner img` задаёт высоту изображений, а высота `.carousel` - высоту всей карусели.

Изображение сидят внутри карусели как в матрёшке. Карусель может быть больше своих изображений, но если увеличить изображения, они растянут и карусель. А если уменьшить карусель, она сожмёт изображения внутри себя.

От высоты карусели зависит размер боковых панелей, на которые нажимают, чтобы перейти к соседнему слайду.

И индикаторы по умолчанию стоят у нижней границы карусели. Если карусель выше изображений, то индикаторы выходят за пределы изображений и встают под ними. Такие индикаторы нужно перекрасить с учётом фона страницы.

```
.carousel {
  height: 500px !important;
}
.carousel-inner img {
  height: 400px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #000;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel {
  height: 500px !important;
}
.carousel-inner img {
  height: 400px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #000;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/c69/f9c/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/650x250/9c6/cf9/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x200/69c/9cf/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

### То и другое одновременно

Отменяем ограничение на `max-width` и используем `min-width: 100%;` вместо `width: 100%;`, чтобы слишком широкие изображения выходили за края экрана и сохраняли свои пропорции.

Чтобы отцентрировать изображения, края которых выходят за границы экрана, нужен`position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateХ(-50%);` вместо `margin: 0 auto;`.

Точно так же позволяем изображениям выходить за верхний и нижний края карусели. Задаём им минимальную высоту и центрируем их по вертикали.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/601g6n69/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel {
  height: 400px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
}
.carousel-inner img {
  left: 50%;
  max-width: none !important;
  min-height: 400px;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/c69/f9c/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/650x250/9c6/cf9/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x200/69c/9cf/" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: А как сделать изображение на всю ширину но с фиксированной высотой? Допустим в 400 px.

Comment: @Александр Можно объединить оба варианта, но пропорции изображения исказятся. Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: @Александр Переделал ответ, чтобы сохранить пропорции слишком широких изображений. Дал им выйти за края экрана и отцентрировал.